# Postgres: Retrieve first n words from column

Tags: postgresql

I know that I can do a text search in Postgres with TextSearch and get some result with

```
select ts_headline('german',content, tq, 'MaxFragments=4, MinWords=5, MaxWords=12,
       ShortWord=3, StartSel = <strong>, StopSel = </strong>') as highlight, ...
FROM to_tsquery('german', 'test') tq ...
```

Is there a similar way to apply to `content` the same limitations? i.e. to get directly up to 12 words from the column `content`.

Comment: What do you mean? You want the query result to be a substring of `content` that consists of the first 12 words?

Comment: Yes - that's what I'm looking for. I thought there is a function instead of manually splitting and counting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions:

```
SELECT (regexp_match(
           regexp_replace(content, '[^\w\s]+', ' ', 'g'),
           '^\s*((?:\w+\s+){9}\w+)'
       ))[1] FROM ...
```

That will first replace everything that is not a space or alphanumerical character with a space and then return the first 10 words.

Comment: Looks great as long as I don't have HTML encoded data in it ;-) All <> are gone - as well line breaks (which I don't care). If there is any update I'll test it on Tuesday